# validator.isAlpha in a mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose-schema

Not sure if this is possible to do but in the validatorjs documentation that a "-" can be passed into the options to ignore white space when validating. Can this be achieved in a mongoose schema when validating a new document?

This would be the object in question, I just don't know how to pass this option to the isAlpha in the above format.

Thanks in advance!

```
   name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A Tour must have a name!'],
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      maxlength: [40, 'A Tour name must have no more than 40 characters'],
      minlength: [10, 'A Tour name must have at least 10 characters'],
      validate: [
        validator.isAlpha,
        'A tour name must only contain characters between A-Z',
      ],
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine if you wish to use validator and just add an exception for the spaces.
Adding a validate property and returning your 'required' validator with appropriate method (isAlpha) in this case

```
 validate: {
                validator: (val) =>
                    validator.isAlpha(val, ["en-US"], { ignore: " " }),
                message: "A tour must only  contain characters",
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the end result after hunting around. Just need to get a dynamic location now

```
validate: {
validator: function (val) {
  return validator.isAlpha(val, ['en-GB'], {
    ignore: ' ',
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This work with an Error Message.
You can specify any chars to ignore in object { ignore: " -" }; // that means allow white spaces and Hyphen (" " and "-")

```html
{
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "A tour must have a name!"],
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      maxlength: [40, "A tour name length must have >=40 char"],
      minlength: [10, "A tour name length must have <10 char"],
      validate: {
        validator: val => validator.isAlpha(val, ["en-US"], { ignore: " -" }), //" =" => " " & "-"
        message: "A tour name must only contain characters between A-Z",
      },
    },
```

This was not obvious for me in documentation for the first time to...
[https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js/][1]